# Fetch mail Message thread in .net based on a subject

Tags: c#, .net, pop3

I am currently using openPOP Library to fetch mails in my .net App. But it seems like there is no way in openPOP library to search a mail based on subject other than fetching the entire messages and search from the retrieved messages.But it takes a lot of time for such operation.

Following is my code to fetch a mail based on Search criterion of "HeaderVal":

```
 HeaderVal = "Case detail LEA/ED/05111802";
 var client = new Pop3Client();

 using (Pop3Client client2 = new Pop3Client())
 {
     // Connect to the server
     client.Connect("pop.gmail.com", 995, true);

     client.Authenticate("recent:" + userName, password, AuthenticationMethod.UsernameAndPassword);
     //var count = client.GetMessageCount();

     // Get the number of messages in the inbox
     int messageCount = client.GetMessageCount();

     //  MessageHeader messageHeader =;
     // We want to download all messages
     List<Message> allMessages = new List<Message>(messageCount);

     //var requiredMessage = allMessages.Where(x=>x.Headers == HeaderVal).

     for (int i = messageCount; i > 0; i--)
     {
         allMessages.Add(client.GetMessage(i));
     }

     var RequiredMessage = allMessages.Where(x=>x.Headers.Subject.ToString().ToLower().Trim() == HeaderVal.ToLower().Trim());
}
```

I also need to fetch the replies made to that respective mail, which am not able to get.Please suggest if it can be achieved using openPOP or any other library which solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

`POP3` has no search facilities.  It is a very simple protocol for listing how many messages exist and downloading them.

If you wish to do a server search you will need to use a more full featured protocol such as `IMAP`, `ActiveSync`, or depending on the server, custom HTTP based libraries.

There are literally dozens of different `IMAP` libraries about you can use.

Comment: Note: suggesting libraries is outside the scope of StackOverflow.

Comment: Suggesting libraries is allowed, asking for them is not.

Comment: Fair enough.  I'm not in the .net space so I don't have good suggestions, however, searching the .net and imap tags together should give a pretty overview of what people are using, and sample code.

Comment: @Max Thanks for the input.

Comment: I'm a bit biased because I'm the author, but [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) is probably the best IMAP library for .NET. It's also the only free/open-source IMAP library for .NET being actively maintained.